# HostType("VS IDE") does not load Experimental hive

Tags: c#, vs-extensibility

When running unit tests in my project, a few are decorated with a `HostType("VS IDE")` attributes to indicate that the test must take place within Visual Studio to succeed.  This works perfectly for any test that does not interact with my VSIX package.

From my looking around it seems that the VS IDE host loads the default standard configuration for Visual Studio instead of the 12.0Exp experimental hive in which my package is registered.

I can make this work by setting up testsettings that configure the host and it's parameters, but then all my tests run in that adapter.  I've tried using the generated XML as a parameter to the host type but it doesn't seem to work.

`<VSSDKTestHostRunConfig name="VS IDE" HiveKind="DevEnv" HiveName="12.0Exp" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/SDK/Tools/IdeHostAdapter/2006/06" />`

`[TestMethod]
[HostType("VS IDE", @"<VSSDKTestHostRunConfig name=""VS IDE"" HiveKind=""DevEnv"" HiveName=""12.0Exp"" xmlns=""http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/SDK/Tools/IdeHostAdapter/2006/06"" />")]
public void PackageLoadTest()`

Is there any way to use attributes or code to configure the VS IDE host adapter for my unit tests dependent on that environment?

Answer (score 1):

Add something like:

```
[TestProperty("VsHiveName", "12.0Exp")]
```

or

```
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestProperty(VsIdeTestHostContants.TestPropertyName.RegistryHiveName, "12.0Exp")]
```